# Anyone who can suggest some good references for Httparty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

Hey I am new to Httparty. I can fetch data but have problem posting using Httparty. Anyone who can suggest some good references for that? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Please add more information to your question, including: What you tried; What happened; What you expected to happen; A sample of your relevant source code. As it is, there is not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying. I first asked this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406428/sending-form-data-to-remote-rails-application-using-httparty   No replies back. So I thought maybe I should start readying from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't a lot of references out there for HTTParty. Primarily, the [readme](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) and [examples](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/tree/master/examples) in their github repo. You could potentially go through their code to get a feel as well. Here's a quick example of a post using the HTTParty mixin:

```
class Emailer
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'api.emailer.com'

  def send(username, password, to, subject, body)
    options = { username: username, 
                password: password, 
                to: to, 
                subject: subject,
                body: body }
    post('/send', options)
  end
end
```

While your question was about HTTParty, and I've had to use that in the past, I've generally liked [Typheous](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus) better. You may want to take a peek at that. I'm sure there are plenty of other HTTP Clients out there too. Those are the two I've worked with, and I've tended to prefer Typheous.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem is I don't know how to read from a form. Anyways, I would also ty Typheous and see if I can post the data.

Comment: Hey Chris, I finally was able to post successfully using httparty. I mostly had problem on retrieval part in the server side controller which I found how to do that.